# why does loop terminate before alert statement when setting an html attribute to a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to debug the following loop.  I never make it to the last alert("YO").  Also, interestingly, I am expecting 5 alert(typeof ...), but I am only getting 4.  I can't for the life of me figure out why this is.

```js
function Question(topic,question,choices,correctAnswer){
    this.topic = topic;
    this.question = question;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.userAnswer = null;
}

var allQuestions;
allQuestions = [
    new Question("Addition", "What is 8 + 8?", [16, 18, 64, 28], 16),
    new Question("Subtraction", "What is 23-8?", [16, 15, 14, 17], 15),
    new Question("Multiplication", "What is 8 * 8?", [16, 18, 64, 36], 64),
    new Question("Division", "What is 48/16", [3, "3/2", 4, "8/3"], 3),
    new Question("Imaginary Numbers", "What is \u221A(-1)^8?", ["i", "-i", 1, -1], 1)
];


function qToHTML(question) {
    var header = "<h2>" + question.topic + "</h2>";
    var qText = "<p>" + question.question + "</p>";
    var options = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < question.choices.length; i++) {
        options += "<input type='radio' name='" + question.topic + "' value ='" + question.choices[i] + "'>" + question.choices[i] + "<br>"
    }
    var wrapper = "<div class='question'></div>";

    var HTMLstring;
    HTMLstring = header + qText + options;
    $("#question-box").append(HTMLstring).wrap(wrapper);
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    //render questions
    for(var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++){
        qToHTML(allQuestions[i]);
    }

    //collect and check user answers
    $('form').on('submit', function() {
        var numCorrect = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++){

            // collect answers
            var currentQ = allQuestions[i];
            currentQ.userAnswer = $("input[name=" + currentQ.topic + "]:checked").val();
            alert(typeof currentQ.correctAnswer);

            // check answers
            if (currentQ.correctAnswer == currentQ.userAnswer) {
                numCorrect++;
            }
        }
        window.alert('YO');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic Quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H1>Dynamic Quiz</H1>
        <form>
            <div id="question-box"
                <!--
                <div class="question">
                    <h2></h2>
                    <p></p>
                    <input type="radio" name="" value="">
                    <input type="radio" name="" value="">
                    <input type="radio" name="" value="">
                    <input type="radio" name="" value="">
                </div>-->
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Also, I would strongly recommend using `console.log` for debugging instead of alerts!

Comment: word.  I added the complete code

Comment: also, I can't use console.log because I'm using the webstorm IDE.  See my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417359/prompt-and-alert-javascript-commands-in-webstorm/26426350?noredirect=1#comment41501978_26426350

Comment: I don't see any point in posting this code in a snippet without the corresponding html and libraries ...

Comment: I thought it would be bad ettiquette to post the whole code

Comment: Wow, I did not see that stack overflow has inserted a option to run code snippet's. That's really good! But hey, I think T J is right. I speak for myself, but if I'm gonna help you with a problem, I do not mind seeing your code as it is.

Comment: Please don't put commentary about your edits (or words like 'edit'/'update') into the question yourself - there's an "Edit Summary" box you can use for exactly that every time you make an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) doesn't have quotes around the value. This fails when the name has a space in it.

So use: `$("input[name='" + currentQ.topic + "']:checked").val();`

Instead of: `$("input[name=" + currentQ.topic + "]:checked").val();`

This was causing a jQuery error and a javascript exception, which immediately terminates your code.

Full, runnable example:

```js
function Question(topic,question,choices,correctAnswer){
    this.topic = topic;
    this.question = question;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.userAnswer = null;
}

var allQuestions;
allQuestions = [
    new Question("Addition", "What is 8 + 8?", [16, 18, 64, 28], 16),
    new Question("Subtraction", "What is 23-8?", [16, 15, 14, 17], 15),
    new Question("Multiplication", "What is 8 * 8?", [16, 18, 64, 36], 64),
    new Question("Division", "What is 48/16", [3, "3/2", 4, "8/3"], 3),
    new Question("Imaginary Numbers", "What is \u221A(-1)^8?", ["i", "-i", 1, -1], 1)
];


function qToHTML(question) {
    var header = "<h2>" + question.topic + "</h2>";
    var qText = "<p>" + question.question + "</p>";
    var options = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < question.choices.length; i++) {
        options += "<input type='radio' name='" + question.topic + "' value ='" + question.choices[i] + "'>" + question.choices[i] + "<br>"
    }
    var wrapper = "<div class='question'></div>";

    var HTMLstring;
    HTMLstring = header + qText + options;
    $("#question-box").append(HTMLstring).wrap(wrapper);
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    //render questions
    for(var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++){
        qToHTML(allQuestions[i]);
    }

    //collect and check user answers
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
        var numCorrect = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++){

            // collect answers
            var currentQ = allQuestions[i];
            currentQ.userAnswer = $("input[name='" + currentQ.topic + "']:checked").val();
            alert(typeof currentQ.correctAnswer);

            // check answers
            if (currentQ.correctAnswer == currentQ.userAnswer) {
                numCorrect++;
            }
        }
        window.alert('YO');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic Quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H1>Dynamic Quiz</H1>
        <form>
            <div id="question-box"
                <!--
                <div class="question">
                    <h2></h2>
                    <p></p>
                    <input type="radio" name="" value="">
                    <input type="radio" name="" value="">
                    <input type="radio" name="" value="">
                    <input type="radio" name="" value="">
                </div>-->
            </div>

            <input type="button" value="submit">
        </form>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the issue for me.  Question though, why did that stop the alert("YO").  The events seem completely unrelated...

Comment: It was causing a jQuery error and a javascript exception, which immediately terminates your code.

Comment: @dave Instead of deleting a non-working answer and posting a new one, please edit your existing answer and then undelete it... the deleted answers are still visible for a part of community...

Answer (score 2):

While using attribute selector, If the attribute value contains more than one word, You should include the attribute value inside quotes.

Currently The following line

```
$("input[name=" + currentQ.topic + "]:checked")
```

Throws error when it finds the value "Imaginary Numbers" and the script execution stops, which is why further alerts doesn't appear.

---

```js
function Question(topic, question, choices, correctAnswer) {
  this.topic = topic;
  this.question = question;
  this.choices = choices;
  this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
  this.userAnswer = null;
}

var allQuestions;
allQuestions = [
  new Question("Addition", "What is 8 + 8?", [16, 18, 64, 28], 16),
  new Question("Subtraction", "What is 23-8?", [16, 15, 14, 17], 15),
  new Question("Multiplication", "What is 8 * 8?", [16, 18, 64, 36], 64),
  new Question("Division", "What is 48/16", [3, "3/2", 4, "8/3"], 3),
  new Question("Imaginary Numbers", "What is \u221A(-1)^8?", ["i", "-i", 1, -1], 1)
];


function qToHTML(question) {
  var header = "<h2>" + question.topic + "</h2>";
  var qText = "<p>" + question.question + "</p>";
  var options = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < question.choices.length; i++) {
    options += "<input type='radio' name='" + question.topic + "' value ='" + question.choices[i] + "'>" + question.choices[i] + "<br>"
  }
  var wrapper = "<div class='question'></div>";

  var HTMLstring;
  HTMLstring = header + qText + options;
  $("#question-box").append(HTMLstring).wrap(wrapper);
}



$(document).ready(function() {
  //render questions
  for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
    qToHTML(allQuestions[i]);
  }

  //collect and check user answers
  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {

      // collect answers
      var currentQ = allQuestions[i];
      currentQ.userAnswer = $("input[name='" + currentQ.topic + "']:checked").val();
      alert(typeof currentQ.correctAnswer);

      // check answers
      if (currentQ.correctAnswer == currentQ.userAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }
    window.alert('YO');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dynamic Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <H1>Dynamic Quiz</H1>
  <form>
    <div id="question-box" <!-- <div class="question">
      <h2></h2>
      <p></p>
      <input type="radio" name="" value="">
      <input type="radio" name="" value="">
      <input type="radio" name="" value="">
      <input type="radio" name="" value="">
    </div>-->
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean "Imaginary Numbers" should be "Imaginary-numbers"?  If so, that solved the second part of my question--now I get 5 alerts for typeof.  But I am still not getting the last alert('YO!').

Comment: @Goodword I wonder why you accepted the late answer which is the same as my answer..! and I'm getting the alert `YO`  in the above snippet...

Comment: @TJ +1 to you, you did make it in first. Sorry if I duplicated your answer I was working on it before your answer was posted.

Comment: @dave never mind, BTW it is better to edit and update your answer rather than posting a new one... :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran it in console and I found that you have a topic what contain a white sapce.

```
new Question("Imaginary Numbers", "What is \u221A(-1)^8?", ["i", "-i", 1, -1], 1)
```

and I got an error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=Imaginary Numbers]:checked
A solution is to remove the space from the topic Imaginary Numbers,

```
new Question("Imaginary_Numbers", "What is \u221A(-1)^8?", ["i", "-i", 1, -1], 1)
```